# Condensing/Optimizing jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code for sliding down a hidden content area. It works, but I suspect it's too clumsy and may fire too many requests or events. Can someone suggest a way to combinee these functions more efficiently?

```
$(".toggler").click(function (event){
event.stopPropagation();
$("#mobile-top").animate({'height':'toggle'}, 250);
});

$("#mobile-top").click(function(event){
event.stopPropagation();
});

$('.toggler').toggle(function() {
    $(this).html('Close This Box <em class="fa fa-chevron-up"></em>');
}, function() {
    $(this).html('Connect With Us! <em class="fa fa-chevron-down"></em>');
});

$('html').click(function(){
$("#mobile-top").slideUp();
$(".toggler").html('Connect With Us! <em class="fa fa-chevron-down"></em>');
});
```

Comment: Working code that you want improvement suggestions for generally belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code could be improved by using variables when you can especially when using a certain selector more than once.
and try and use ID's not classes.

**EDIT**

[**UPDATED JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8e1auupr/1/)

Here is the code that is working and wont get confused when you click outside in the HTML area. (note that while naming a variable it can't contain a - character like I had put before)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var toggler = $("#toggler");
  var mobileTop = $("#mobile-top");
  //top drop-down content animation
  toggler.click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    mobileTop.slideToggle(250);
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    $(this).html('Connect With Us! <em class="fa fa-chevron-down"></em>');
    $(".open").html('Close This Box <em class="fa fa-chevron-up"></em>');
  });
  $('html').click(function(){
    mobileTop.slideUp(250);
    toggler.html('Connect With Us! <em class="fa fa-chevron-down"></em>');
    toggler.removeClass('open');
  });
  $(mobileTop).click(function(event){ 
    event.stopPropagation(); 
  });
});
```

And this should be more efficient as well.

a good read:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/10-ways-to-instantly-increase-your-jquery-performance--net-5551

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed one issue, maybe you can help figure out. When I drop it down, then click outside the area ('html') to slide it back up, and then try to drop it down again, the order is reversed. i.e. it says "close this box" when it's already closed and vice-versa. I think clicking outside the area (this line: $("#toggler").html('Connect With Us! <em class="fa fa-chevron-down"></em>');) resets the ordering. Is there a way around this?

Comment: If you could create a JSFIDDLE or CodePen I could help you out more for sure

Comment: I created jsfiddle but it's not working the same way for some reason: http://jsfiddle.net/8e1auupr/. You can look at the demo for a more accurate version: http://76.163.3.49/

Comment: @GeorgeC check my updated answer it should fix your issues and also using animation toggle with slideUp was causing it to not slide smoothly and so I just stuck to the slideToggle for all instances.

Comment: Thanks, in addition, to prevent sliding up when people click on the dropped-down area the code needs:

jQuery(mobileTop).click(function(event){
event.stopPropagation();
});